# Entfernung von/zwischen zwei Städten

Tags: word-choice, preposition

Welche Form ist schöner. Sind beide korrekt?

> 280 km entsprechen der Entfernung von (zwischen) Berlin und Hamburg.
>
> 280 km entsprechen der Entfernung von (zwischen) Berlin bis (nach) Hamburg.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So ist es richtig:

> 280 km entsprechen der Entfernung **zwischen** Berlin **und** Hamburg.
>   280 km entsprechen der Entfernung **von** Berlin **nach** Hamburg.

Comment: Willkommen auf dem Stackexchange der deutschen Sprache. Du kannst eine [Tour] der Seite nehmen. Weitere Fragen darüber, wie sie funktioniert, beantwortet dir das [Help].

Comment: „Entsprechen“ ist Quark.

Comment: @Carsten: Warum? In folgendem Kontext würde ich den Satz genau so schreiben: "*Von Sonqopata bis Sumaqpicchu sind es 280 km. 280 km **entsprechen** der Entfernung ...*" (oder eben: "*Diese Entfernung **entspricht**...*").

Comment: @Carsten Quark? was heisst das?

Comment: @Beta: [Quark](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quark_%28Milchprodukt%29) ist normalerweise etwas zu essen. In diesem Zusammenhang bedeutet es aber so viel wie Unsinn, Blödsinn, Quatsch. Siehe Bedeutung [2]: https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Quark

Comment: Sorry, ich hatte nicht gesehen, dass das „entsprechen“ in der Frage war.

Answer (score 2):

Wenn du deine Sätze mit „280 km entsprechen …“ anfängst, steht die Größe von 280 km im Vordergrund und wird mit etwas verglichen, um die Größe zu verdeutlichen.
Wenn es eher um die Entfernung der angegebenen Orte geht, würde ich die Sätze eher so formulieren:

> Die Entfernung zwischen Berlin und Hamburg beträgt 280 km.
>   Die Entfernung von Berlin nach Hamburg beträgt 280 km.

Wobei ich den zweiten Satz eher benutzen würde, wenn es auch das Pendant dazu gibt:

> Die Entfernung von Hamburg nach Berlin beträgt 282 km.

Je nach Richtung gibt es unterschiedliche Entfernungen.
Das wird bei solchen Entfernungen meist nicht der Fall sein, aber „vom Bahnhof zum Museum sind es 3 km“, „vom Museum zum Bahnhof sind es 3,5 km“ ist schon realistischer (und eine weitere Formulierung für eine Entfernungsangabe).